# Button images for UIButton scaling on iPhone 4 much smaller then appearing on simulator or iphone 3

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, interface-builder

The images on a few UIButtons are getting scaled down way smaller on the iPhone 4 compared to how the show up on interface builder, the iPhone simulator or an iPhone 3G.
How can I ensure the button images stay the same size as they appear in IB?

Comment: the problem could be the different resolutions, so as example 100x100 pixels look smaller with 326 ppi (iPhone4) as with 163 ppi (iPhone3G) I think the IB can't help you in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have two images, e.g. one for 320*480 and one for 640*960 screen resolution? E.G one file named myImage.png and one named myImage@2x.png?